# Multiple plots using Matplot lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple plots using matplot lib and pandas using python at once.
Below is how my data looks like.

[image]

Column B has multiple distinct values - about 3K and each value has data for 80 weeks.

I want to plot week vs count plot for each individual value for last 80 weeks.

And if at all it would be possible to save those plots as images.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1 -
Currently trying using this :

```
for x in df.value.unique():
    plt.plot(df['week'],df['count'])
    #plt.title(''+str(x))
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (2000,1000)
    plt.savefig("ts"+ str(x) + ".png")
```

I am trying to plot - counts vs week plots for each value.
So, for each distinct value there will be a single image which would should counts for it for period of time

Comment: Have you already tried something? On Stackoverflow you usually show what you tried first.

Comment: Hi @b0neng4  : 

I am trying to do something like this -
Present in first edit

Answer (score 0):

Create a plt.figure() first and on the end of each iteration call plt.show()

```
for x in df.value.unique():
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(df['value'],df['week'])
    plt.savefig("ts"+ str(x) + ".png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: HI ,
Above is wrong - actually I want to plot a timeseries plot - No of counts vs week for each topic. 
What I am doing right now is - for x in df.value.unique():
    plt.plot(df['week'],df['count'])
    #plt.title(''+str(x))
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (2000,1000)
    plt.savefig("ts"+ str(x) + ".png")

However, when I getting the images in local - those plots are plotting incorrect data.

I have edited the code being used